# How to create a User Provisioning FLow

Tags: user, provisioning

I need to create user provisioning on Connected App but there is no particular guide how to go about it. I can only find bits and pieces. Even Salesforce talk about some util packages for some common applications and a single program which doesn't explain much about the attributes used in it. But not much information about custom provisioning. Does anyone here know how to begin with user provisioning for a custom application.

What I know is I need to create a flow. (Need help in this regard only as there is not much info about how to create a user provisioning flow and use Apex class which extends UserProvisioningPlugin). Then a named credential to connect with third party app.
Note : Here Salesforce is Idp and third party app is Sp.

Answer (score 0):

User Provisioning via Connected Apps is explained in this help article: [Configure User Provisioning for Connected Apps](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=connected_app_user_provisioning_configure.htm&type=5). As the help explains, you'll want to install two packages from the App Exchange to help with user provisioning:  [Salesforce Identity User Provisioning Connectors](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000EeLdWUAV) and the [Salesforce Identity User Provisioning Utils](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000EeLdbUAF) apps. These will provide you with the base Apex classes you need and assist you in creating your flows. One these have been enabled, there will be a User Provisioning Wizard that will help you get started with the provisioning. [Named Credentials](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=named_credentials_about.htm&type=5) are very easy to set up if you have the information you need, especially once the other things are in place.